# Something cause BSOD. A device attached to the system is not functioning

Tags: windows, windows-10, bsod, logging, event-log

For some time now I started getting BSOD screens. Just now after the one `IRQL NOT LESS OR EQUAL`, right after system rebooting I opened `Event Viewer` and the last one error message was:

```
The Network Connection Broker service terminated with the following error: 
A device attached to the system is not functioning.
```

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhDRp.jpg

The BSOD appears after about 7 - 8 hours of PC working.

I saved all events from `Event Viewer -> Windows Logs -> System`: https://gist.github.com/Zx-EvM/a01626e9ef70433a06a9ed6fd29384d5

The last 4 `dmp` files from `C:\Windows\Minidump`: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xpc4d2x2l05vp05/thealldmpfiles.zip

Bugcheck Analysis of `C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP` with WinDbg Preview: https://pastebin.com/xyhYWE41

How can I determine what device (according to the message) actually is broken and cause BSOD screens? The only devices attached is USB Headset, Keyboard and Mouse. Router also I have in ethernet.

I have now using `Windows 10 20H2 19042.867`.

Hardware setup:

```
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3600 @stock
MOBO: ASUS PRIME B350 M-A
RAM: HX430C15PB3K2/16 3000 Mhz
GPU: MSI GTX 1080 GAMING X
```

Comment: Did this start after a Windows update? The March 2021 *series* of updates, recalls and reupdates has caused issues such as BSOD. https://www.windowslatest.com/2021/03/11/microsoft-confirms-windows-10-march-update-is-crashing-some-pcs/ Try the latest patch, or remove all updates this month.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I was unable to install this update. During the installation I was got BSOD with different message.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I also edited my question with adding Bugcheck Analysis of C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP with WinDbg Preview. Maybe the message make sense?

Comment: The BSoD's in question due to the windows update are win32.sys if I remember correctly, and are happening if you have a Kyocera, Zebra and one other printer brand. Also Dymo printers will print empty labels if you install the update that should fix it. Another update was released to fix that issue and Dymo released a fix themselves too. Either install the update that fixes it or uninstall the previous one. Also, if you don't print, it should not BSoD.

Comment: Given the nature of the bugcheck, I would run `verifier.exe` then choose - 'Create Standard Settings" - "Select driver names from a list" - Then you get to choose the drivers you're most suspicious of. Looking at the drivers you have installed by configuring symbols and running: `.reload /f`, then `lme` to get a short list of drivers symbols can't be obtained for and therefore most non-Microsoft, either that or on the Verifier dialog sort by Provider and check all non-Microsoft drivers.  Next time a bugcheck happens it may prove more useful.  Don't forget to run verifier again to disable it.

Comment: @LPChip today I noticed in device manager the some print queries appears for some printer models. But I don't have printer at all. Looks the update did created it by itself. I just delete this update with `wusa /uninstall /kb:5000802` and stopped all updates for 2 months. Hope system will stabilize.